# How to fire a query from OpenLayers to GeoServer to fetch 'the_geom' column in PostGIS table?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, query

I am coloring the polygon shapes of `world_country`. I have OpenLayers in my UI, GeoServer as server and PostGIS as db.
All I want is fire this query:

`select the_geom from world_country where cntryname='China'`

And this query should return shape file of China, so I get it in my UI and can color it.

I am using wfs data layer to fire the query, but I am not getting the selected country. Please suggest what I am missing?

`function init()`

```
{
    $("#heatmapArea").remove();
    $('body').append('<div id="heatmapArea"></div>');

            map = new OpenLayers.Map({
                div: "heatmapArea",
                allOverlays: true,
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                units: "m",
                numZoomLevels: 18,
                maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508,
                                                 20037508, 20037508.34)
            });

var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {numZoomLevels: 20});

      var countryLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Country polygon","http://10.208.22.159:8080/geoserver/wms",{'layers': 'aqp:world_country', transparent: true,}, {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 0.3, deltaX: 0.0013, deltaY: 0.00058});

    var wfsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url:  "http://10.208.22.159:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: "aqp:world_country",
               // featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                geometryName:"the_geom"
            }),
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                strokeWidth: 3,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000"
            }),
            filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
                filters: [
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "cntryname",
                        value: "China"
                    }),
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "cntryname",
                        value: "India"
                    })
                ]
            })
        })

map.addLayers([gmap, countryLayer,wfsLayer]);
           map.zoomToMaxExtent();
           map.zoomIn();
           map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90).getCenterLonLat(), 3);
        }
```